# regex optional capture not working as expected

Tags: javascript, java, regex

I have need to capture **all** elements of a string like this

```
front stuff grp2="abc" middle stuff grp4="xyz" end stuff
```

such that it is broken into these five groups

```
#1: front stuff
#2: grp2="abc"
#3: middle stuff
#4: grp4="xyz"
#5: end stuff
```

This expression does the trick as long as all five sections exist

```
([\s\S]*?)(grp2=\"\S*?\")([\s\S]*?)(grp4=\"\S*?\")([\s\S]*)
```

But if grp4="..." doesn't exist, for example,

```
front stuff grp2="abc" end stuff
```

it of course doesn't match at all.

So okay, I can make the 4th group optional like this, right?

```
([\s\S]*?)(grp2=\"\S*?\")([\s\S]*?)(grp4=\"\S*?\")?([\s\S]*)
```

Apparently wrong. What that produces is this (when grp4 is present)

```
#1: front stuff
#2: grp2="abc"
#3: 
#4: 
#5: middle stuff grp4="xyz" end stuff
```

The 4th group is no longer matched even when it exists.

FWIW, I need all the text (all groups must be capturing groups) because I'm ultimately using this to manipulate the text of groups 2 and 4 (if they exist), and reconstitute the string. Like taking that example string and turning it into this

```
front stuff grp2="123" middle stuff grp4="456" end stuff
```

The behavior is easy to see on regex101.com. I've tried every combination of "optional" I know of. I'm sure I must be doing something dumb, and I've wasted enough time trying to figure it out, so I'm finally asking for help.

Thanks!

Comment: Java and Javascript are different languages, and quite possibly have slightly different dialects of regex. Which are you actually interested in?

Comment: When your third capture group is first tested, it tests against the empty string because you have used the non-greedy operator (it attempts the smallest match and gradually increases the length of the attempted match each time it backtracks). This enables the fourth capture group to also match against the empty string (optional matching) and then the 5th capture group captures the rest of the string. This will always be the case whether or not `grp4="..."` is present in the string.

Comment: @JonSkeet I agree java and javascript are different, but, in this case I think the expressions would be the same (except for the extra escapes in Java). And I do need to do this in both languages, if the solutions would be different. I used javascript syntax in my test case for simplicity.

Comment: @danno57: You're assuming that regular expressions are identical in Java and Javascript. My experience is that there are subtle differences between various dialects of regular expressions - and apart from anything else, your question doesn't say anything about them...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make the `middle stuff` and `grp4` in the middle optional since both have `end stuff`. Your new regex would be `([\\s\\S]*?)(grp2=\"\\S*?\")(?:([\\s\\S]*?)(grp4=\"\\S*?\")){0,1}([\\s\\S]*)`

```
String test = "front stuff grp2=\"abc\" middle stuff grp4=\"xyz\" end stuff";
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("([\\s\\S]*?)(grp2=\"\\S*?\")(?:([\\s\\S]*?)(grp4=\"\\S*?\")){0,1}([\\s\\S]*)");
Matcher m = p.matcher(test);

for(int i=1; i<=m.groupCount(); i++) {
    if(m.group(i)!=null) {
        System.out.println(i+": "+m.group(i));
    }
}
// String test = "front stuff grp2=\"abc\" middle stuff grp4=\"xyz\" end stuff";
// 1: front stuff 
// 2: grp2="abc"
// 3:  middle stuff 
// 4: grp4="xyz"
// 5:  end stuff

// String test = "front stuff grp2=\"abc\" end stuff";
// 1: front stuff 
// 2: grp2="abc"
// 3:  end stuff
```

Comment: Yep, that seems to work! I had tried the {0,1} after the 4th group, but had not thought of doing anything thing with the 3rd group. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The **|** in regex gives you the ability to set an OR option on the mask.

You can use this kind of formula : 
([\s\S]*?)(grp2=\"\S*?\")([\s\S]*?)(grp4=\"\S*?\")([\s\S]*)**|**([\s\S]*?)(grp2=\"\S*?\")([\s\S]*)**|**([\s\S]*)(grp4=\"\S*?\")([\s\S]*)

Here it work even if grp2 doesn't exist or grp4 doesn't exist or both exist.

Hope this help.

Comment: Yes, but it doesn't fulfill my requirement to capture all the groups. It correctly matches grp2 and / or grp4 (2 matches if the both exist as you said), but throws away all the other "stuff", which I need in order to be able to reconstitute the original string with groups 2 and / or 4 modified.